# regex split groups of digits and non-digits not working in Javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I've a simple regex pattern that should split groups of digits and non-digits.
so a string like 12AB34CD should become an array like ["12", "AB", "34", "CD"]
when I use this (http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) tool to test the expression it works fine but it doesn't seem to work in Javascript

```
var code = "12AB34CD";
var regex =  new RegExp(/\d+|\D+/g);
var codeArray = code.split(regex);
console.log(codeArray);
```

this will result in an array but all empty strings ["", "", "", "", ""]

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

JavaScript's regex `split()` doesn't include the separators (the things that matched the regex) - only the things that were in between the separators. That's why you get 5 empty strings - because there are 4 matches for your regex, and around those 4 matches are no other characters.

```
"" "12" "" "AB" "" "34" "" "CD" ""

    ^       ^       ^       ^
    |       |       |       |
    +-------+-------+-------+--- regex (separator) matches
```

Instead, since you actually want the things that match the regex, and not the ones in between, you should just use `.match()` instead of `.split()`, which will give you back all of your matches.

Comment: +1 for actually explaining the problem and providing an alternative.

Answer (score 5):

You can use `match`:

```
code.match(/\d+|\D+/g); //=> ["12", "AB", "34", "CD"]
```